# Visual Studio Styles?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

Studio Styles 2010 ? What is the Best public URL view to Visual Studio Styles? ex: CurrentSettings-2010-04-29.vssettings
Thx,
Catto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a theme sharing site started that's got a bit of traction, not that large, but it has the most in one place I've come across thus far:  **http://studiostyles.info/**  Also, you can [**create a new theme**](http://studiostyles.info/schemes/create), it's a handy little interface to customize things quickly, and any of the themes there you can download in 2008 or 2010 flavors.

There's also a great addon to make this much easier to to yourself in 2010, the [Visual Studio Color Theme Editor](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/20cd93a2-c435-4d00-a797-499f16402378) created by one of the guys at MS.